# Hostednetwork show login page

Tags: vb.net, wifi, hotspot

I'm currently writing a program that opens a wifi hotspot and enables Internet Connection sharing. I've got all of this working with `netsh wlan set hostednetwork` and some WinAPI calls.

Now I'd like to be able to show a login page when a client connects or block some websites/ports/etc.

My idea on this was to monitor the connection between me (the access point) and the client and whenever a packet on port 80 occurs, I send my login page or a "website blocked" page back instead of the real page. Currently the program is able to monitor the connection but I don't know how to send it back to the client.

This is my code (it's a bit long):

```
Dim myIpaddress As IPAddress
Dim theSocket As Socket
Dim receiveBuffer(4096) As Byte

Dim content As String = ""
Dim protocol As String = ""
Dim ipFrom As IPAddress
Dim ipTo As IPAddress
Dim portFrom As UInteger
Dim portTo As UInteger

Sub Listen()
    theSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP)
    For Each int As NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
        If int.Description.Contains("Hosted") Then
            For Each adress As UnicastIPAddressInformation In int.GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses
                If adress.Address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                    myIpaddress = adress.Address
                    BindSocket()
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub BindSocket()
    Try
        theSocket.Bind(New IPEndPoint(myIpaddress, 0))
        theSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, True)
        theSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0})
        receiveBuffer = New Byte(theSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) {}
        theSocket.BeginReceive(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive), Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub OnReceive(ByVal asyncresult As IAsyncResult)

    'Get Length of packet (including header)
    Dim readlength As UInteger = BitConverter.ToUInt16(Byteswap(receiveBuffer, 2), 0)
    portTo = BitConverter.ToUInt16(Byteswap(receiveBuffer, 22), 0)
    portFrom = BitConverter.ToUInt16(Byteswap(receiveBuffer, 24), 0)

    'Get Protocol Type
    If receiveBuffer(9) = 6 Then
        protocol = "TCP"
    ElseIf receiveBuffer(9) = 17 Then
        protocol = "UDP"
    Else
        protocol = "???"
    End If

    'Get IP from and to
    ipFrom = New IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(receiveBuffer, 12))
    ipTo = New IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(receiveBuffer, 16))

    content = ""
    For i = 26 To readlength - 1
        If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(Chr(receiveBuffer(i))) = True Then
            content = content & Chr(receiveBuffer(i))
        Else
            content = content & "."
        End If
    Next


    'TODO how to send my content to the client?

    'Restart the Receiving
    theSocket.BeginReceive(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive), Nothing)
End Sub

Private Function Byteswap(ByVal bytez() As Byte, ByVal index As UInteger)
    Dim result(1) As Byte
    result(0) = bytez(index + 1)
    result(1) = bytez(index)
    Return result
End Function
```

Any ideas?